# Show that the complex potential is $w(z)=k\ln(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers, fluid-dynamics, potential-theory

A line source of strength $k$ has velocity given (in cylindrical polars) by $v_{R}=\frac{k}{R}$, $v_{\theta}=0$. Show that the complex potential for such a source is $w(z)=k\ln(z)$.

My solution so far:

I know that $w=\phi+i\psi$ but i'm unsure where to go from here. (Any hint would be appreciated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream function $\psi(r,\theta)$ in polar coordinates satisfies
$$ v_R = \frac{1}{R}\partial_\theta\psi \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ v_\theta = -\frac{1}{R}\partial_R\psi. $$
Equating this with the given flow field $(v_R,v_\theta) = \left(\dfrac{k}{R},0\right)$ yields
$$ \partial_\theta\psi = k \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ \partial_R\psi = 0. $$
The solution to this two equations is then $\psi(\theta) = k\theta$. Now, we know that the complex potential is given by $w = \phi + i\psi$, where $\phi$ is the velocity potential satisfying $\nabla\phi = (v_R,v_\theta)$. In polar coordinates, 
$$ (v_R, v_\theta) = \left(\partial_R\phi,\frac{1}{R}\partial_\theta\phi\right) = \left(\frac{k}{R},0\right). $$
Solving for $\phi$ we find that $\phi(R) = k\ln R$. Finally, 
\begin{align*}
w = \phi + i\psi = k\ln R + ik\theta = k\left(\ln R + i\theta\right) = k\ln z.
\end{align*}
Here, I am choosing the principal branch of the complex logarithm.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response , I was wondering if you could explain your notation regarding the partial derivatives and how you solved for $\phi$

Comment: @Gibberish Sure. $\partial_R\phi$ means $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial R}$. Solving $\partial_\theta\phi = 0$ yields $\phi = f(R)$ where $f(R)$ is some function of $R$. Now, differentiating this with respect to $R$ gives $\partial_R\phi = f'(R) = \frac{k}{R}$, which implies that $f(R) = k\ln R$. Observe here that I ignore the constant of integration (: